# Fullscreen Image Intent with no Delete option

Tags: android

Currently I am showing a Bitmap in a fullscreen intent using the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/png");
startActivity(intent);
```

The issue I have is that it opens a gallery on some devices, whereas I just want to allow the user to view the image, that's all. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just show a full screen image view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To elaborate on my comment about just using an ImageView:

```
ImageView v = new ImageView(this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
v.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

getContentView().addView(v);
```

Or something like this.